# Token replacement of .config files inside a nuget (powershell or AzureDevOps task)

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have a pipline in AzureDevOps with this stages:

- Build: Build and produce some nugets (using cake build). The nuget contains a tokenized web.config for some settings, like `"value=#{tokenName}"`.
- Deploy to environment X: that just need to replace the tokens inside the web.config in the nuget and push that to a nuget repo. (this for diferentes environments).

I just wonder a easy way to get this done.

I know there is the AzureDevOps task "Replace tokens" that can achieve this replacement but this will require unpackaging all the nuget(s), replace and pack again. Which is a time consuming task with large nugets.

I thought to made this faster if I just unpack the matching .config files from the nuget, transform them and then pack those file again. This will be very quick.
The thing is that in this case the job need to be done in powershell with the tokens gettting replaced by values in a azuredevops variable group.

If i have a variable group called "Dev" with a variable called "IdentityService.BaseUrl"

I've tried like this in powershell:

```
    $content = "Example file string with token #{IdentityService.BaseUrl} end"
    $variableName = [Regex]::Matches($content, '(?<=#{)(.*?)(?=})') | Select -ExpandProperty Value
    
    # variableName is now "IdentityService.BaseUrl"
    
    Write-Host "Value of $variableName is $($variableName)"
    # This will print: Value of IdentityService.BaseUrl is IdentityService.BaseUrl
    # I need to print the name of the variable and the variable value from the azureDevOpsGroup
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to your current situation, we cannot use the double variables. In the azure devops pipeline If we can determine the first variable(like set the value in the variables), then we can use the script `$(${{variables.variableName}})` to help us find the real value.

But in your script, the first variable cannot be determined, so we recommend if it is possible, you can use the if()eles() to help you set the first variables.